# Why does my sister's character have the default skin every time I join her server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting

Every time I join my sister's server, her character has the default skin (Steve).

What could be causing this?

Comment: What server? (Pocket or PC?) | Also, are you connected to the internet and are you even logged in? @Jojo

Answer (score 2):

## There may be two reasons.

### 1. Your game is pirated.

If you did not buy Minecraft from the [website](https://minecraft.net/), it is probably a pirated one. If you downloaded it for free on some other website, it is pirated. Pirating is bad and illegal. Don't be pirates kids.

### 2. She doesn't have a skin.

If she did not download any skins online, she would be using the default skin, Steve.

**That's all the reasons I can think about, if there are any more reasons, feel free to write a comment.**